# Forwarding traffic coming from SSH tunnel to VPN tunnel on a Linux device

Tags: iptables, ip, vpn, ssh-tunneling, route

I want to route network traffic that comes from one end of an ssh tunnel (constructed by ssh dynamic port-forwarding) into one end of a VPN tunnel.

Given four Linux devices A, B, C and D, for example, I want to make a network traffic route

```
A --ssh_tunnel--> B ------> C
```

to

```
A --ssh_tunnel--> B --GRE_tunnel--> D ------> C
```

All the IP addresses of these devices are static **except C which is dynamic**. 
To make the above topology, I properly configured device D and confirmed that the [GRE tunnel](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.tunnel.gre.html) is successfully established.

**However I could not find how to configure device B in order to route traffic that comes from A through the ssh tunnel to the GRE tunnel which is established between B and D**. Since the IP address of C is dynamic, destination-based routing which can be configured on B (using `route`) is not possible. Actually I tried to configure device B with `ip` and `iptables` command lines to apply source based routing, but I could not reach a solution.

Comment: just to give a helpful hint: did you try or searched for masquerading in iptables? With this you can reach portforwarding, you can define interfaces instead of static IP's with this, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to forward a SSH connection all the way down to C, you could e.g. make the SSH endpoint on B a dedicated user account, and then use the iptables `owner` module to match `--uid-owner username` in order to get that traffic to go out through the interface towards D.